# Delete the file manually for day to day process

Tags: php

I've created a log file for day to day processing and  i want to delete the old files generated before 2 days.

Comment: can you rephrase your question in english...

Comment: Can you please throw some extra light over your words? It is not interpretable.

Answer (score 1):

In case you use Linux

```
find /var/spool/sms -mtime +2 -type f | xargs rm -f
```

All files in `/var/spool/sms` older than 2 days will be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

> [PHP unlink  — Deletes a file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)

Answer (score 0):

Probably if you are on LInux platform you can use [cron](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/) .